# NIntegrate with BesselJ, slow convergence

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I have just got a very good [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132581/nintegrate-for-integrant-with-an-obvious-singularity) to my other question, related to use of `NIntegrate` and tried to apply it to another situation:

```
t = 0.2; w = 1; a = 4/w^2; K = k*Sin[t]; k = 2 Pi;

XX[lf_, mf_, l_, mg_, p_, r_] := Abs[YY[lf, mf, l, mg, p, r]]^2;
YY[lf_, mf_, l_, mg_, p_, r_] := WignerD[{lf, mf, l}, t] BesselJ[mf - mg, K r] Sqrt[K/(2 Pi)];

MLG[lf_, l_, mg_, p_, r_] := Sum[XX[lf, ii, l, mg, p, r], {ii, -lf, lf, 1}];
Res1[r_?NumericQ] := (MLG[2, 1, 3, 0, r] - 
 MLG[2, -1, 1, 0, r])/(MLG[2, 1, 3, 0, r] + MLG[2, -1, 1, 0, r]);

NIntegrate[r Res1[r], {r, 0, 1000}, MaxPoints -> 500000, PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

and what I get is

[image]

A little bit about function `Res1`:

1. the integral over $r^2$ (cylindrical coord. axial vector) on the domain $\{0, \infty \}$ must be zero

This is my ultimate goal. So ideally I do not integrate from 0 to 1000 as it is in the code, I need the integral from 0 to $\infty$ and obtain something close to zero.

2. the "Bad boy" - Bessel obeys the relation:

$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^R rdr J^2(ar) = \frac{R}{\pi a}$

so there might be a way to tame the oscillatory behavior within `Res1`.

The function looks like this

[image]

I have tried to use a brute force - Gaussian quadrature, but it seems like depending on the value of the upper integration limit I get very different answers within the range $\pm 0.5$. Is there a trick to make this evaluation work correctly?

Comment: @Ms Tais: Executing your code, I obtain NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand r Res1[r] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1000}}.

Comment: @user64494 Yeah, my bad, I fixed it. Sorry. Now it does not work in a proper way.

Comment: @Anton Antonov Well, it is possible, but I have just played around with those using Oscilatory method for $r\in \{0, 1000\}$, and the best I get is $~0.07...$ and the message that the integral failed to converge and the best it can do for me is this answer+error estimates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insight can be obtained by plotting `r Res1[r]` (with `t = 1/5` used for increased precision).

```
Plot[r Res1[r], {r, 0, 20}, AspectRatio -> .5/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

After an initial transient, the curve appears to be almost periodic.  To investigate this further, consider oscillations at `r == 1000` and `r == 1000000`.  The periods there are obtained by

```
r1 = r /. FindRoot[r Res1[r], {r, 996}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* 996.000670616390157849961696210 *)
r2 = r /. FindRoot[r Res1[r], {r, 998.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* 998.517418096292514726985805578 *)
r3 = r /. FindRoot[r Res1[r], {r, 999995.2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* 999995.189014480314603208960429 *)
r4 = r /. FindRoot[r Res1[r], {r, 999997.7}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* 999997.705759254153466573546910 *)
r2 - r1
(* 2.51674747990235687702410937 *)
r4 - r3
(* 2.51674477383886336458648 *)
```

So the periods are nearly identical.  Moreover, so are the curves themselves, as can be seen from.

```
Plot[{r  Res1[r] /. r -> s + r1, r  Res1[r] /. r -> s + r3}, {s, 0, 10}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

However, they are not precisely identical.

```
NIntegrate[r Res1[r], {r, r1, r2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* 0.0000819173063738409068656216604082 *)
NIntegrate[r Res1[r], {r, r3, r4}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* 8.16930968934193286777117962325*10^-8 *)
```

The integral over a single oscillation is decreasing at just slightly faster than `1/r`, based on these two values of `r`.  If this relationship holds as `r` goes to `Infinity`, the total integral converges.  But, if the integral over a single oscillation eventually decreases as `1/r` or slower, the total integral does not converge.  It is evident from this simple analysis that integration from `0` to some very large number in order to show that the integral to infinity is zero is impractical.

**Addendum**

`Res1` can be simplified substantially by

```
lb = BesselJ[n, 2 \[Pi] r Sin[t]] /. n -> Range[0, 5];
Simplify[(MLG[2, 1, 3, 0, r] - MLG[2, -1, 1, 0, r])/
    (MLG[2, 1, 3, 0, r] + MLG[2, -1, 1, 0, r]), r > 0];
resimp = Collect[Numerator[%], lb, FullSimplify]/Collect[Denominator[%], lb, FullSimplify]
(* (4 BesselJ[0, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 (-1 + Cos[3/5]) Sin[1/10]^2 - 
    4 BesselJ[4, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 (-1 + Cos[3/5]) Sin[1/10]^2 + 
      BesselJ[3, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 (2 + 3 Cos[1/5] + 6 Cos[2/5] + 5 Cos[3/5]) Sin[1/10]^2 - 
    2 BesselJ[1, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 (3 - 4 Cos[1/5] + 3 Cos[2/5]) Sin[1/5]^2 + 
    8 BesselJ[5, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 Sin[1/10]^4 Sin[1/5]^2)/
  (16 BesselJ[2, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 Cos[1/10]^4 (1 - 2 Cos[1/5])^2 - 
    2 BesselJ[1, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 (-2 + Cos[2/5] + Cos[4/5]) + 
      BesselJ[3, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 (9 + 4 Cos[1/5] + 7 Cos[2/5]) Sin[1/5]^2 + 
      8 BesselJ[5, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 Sin[1/10]^4 Sin[1/5]^2 + 
      8 BesselJ[0, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 Sin[1/10]^2 Sin[3/10]^2 + 
      8 BesselJ[4, 2 π r Sin[1/5]]^2 Sin[1/10]^2 Sin[3/10]^2) *)
```

I believe that further simplification is possible by combining Bessel functions, but `FullSimplify` apparently is unable to do so.

Comment: You made a serious progress. Have you tried to find the asymptotics of r*resimp as r approches infinity?

Comment: I did that. The result (see here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivci16zs828d93a/Asymptotic.pdf?dl=0) suggests the integral of r*Res1[r] over the interval $[0,\infty)$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry, I did not succeed to insert @bbgodfrey in the beginnings of my comments.

Comment: @bbgodfrey as far as I got you, the convergence is questionable, correct? Probably, this is a good question for Mathematics forum then. Thank you!

Comment: @MsTais  I am reasonably confident that the integral does not converge.  And, as you suggest, this now is becoming more a mathematics than a Mathematica problem, which could be posed at [math.se].  I do have a bit more material to add to my answer, which may be helpful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Oh, yeah, if you have anything to add, which could be helpful, it is great! I am looking forward. I do not have enough background to perform mathematically strict convergence analysis. Links and/or references to the books are very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If we inspect the function `Res1(r)`, we can see that is the form $(x-y)/(x+y)$, so we can write it as $2x/(x+y)-1$, and in the line of the above post:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
Total@(NIntegrate[(2 r MLG[2, 1, 3, 0, 
       r]/(MLG[2, 1, 3, 0, r] + MLG[2, -1, 1, 0, r])) - 
   r, {r, #, # + 5}, 
  Method -> {"OscillatorySelection", 
    "TermwiseOscillatory" -> True, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 5] & /@
 Table[j, {j, 0, 1000, 5}])]

 {3.19624, 0.0756571}
```

From 0 to 10000:

```
{31.1375, 0.152549}
```

and from 0 to 100000:

```
{306.902, 0.266373}
```

I have realized that `Res1` has a numerator that is a sum of oscillatory terms, so I say NIntegrate that separate each term with `Method -> {"OscillatorySelection","TermwiseOscillatory" -> True`. I have used a PC Desktop Intel i7-3770 QuadCore with Windows 7 (64 bits). I cannot assure that my code is faster, but it seems to be.

On the other hand, your integral seems to increase and not be close to zero, as $r\rightarrow\infty$. That is probably because your integrand is not so symmetrical in its oscillations:

[image]

Please check.

Comment: This is strange, that you don't get the error message. In my case I still get "The integral failed to converge after 9 recursive bisections...", which, I suppose, in this case means that the result is just garbage.

Comment: @MsTais, please, take a look now to see if useful...

Comment: yeah, it seems like all of us get basically the same result: it does not converge. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat different approach is

```
Sum[NIntegrate[r *Res1[r], {r, j, j + 50}, {Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"},   WorkingPrecision -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 5], {j, 0, 950, 50}] // Timing
```

> {150.906, 0.076008561771}

To verify it

```
Sum[NIntegrate[r *Res1[r] + 0.01, {r, j, j + 50}, {Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 5], {j, 0, 950, 50}] -   10 // Timing
```

> {144.813, 0.0760084559}